# how can I use a c++ library with no source code, in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Ok,
I have a library that were wrote in C++, I don't have the source code, I just have 3 files:

MFSSDM with extensions: dll, h and lib.

and I want to use it in a Project in Visual C# (Visual Studio 2010 or 2012)

What could be the fastest way of doing this?

rubenc

Answer (score 6):

Use these:

1. DllImport - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28VS.71%29.aspx)
2. Wrapper class - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/67cc9eea-a4fe-48bd-b8d5-f3c8051ba896